# Why can I not find my Contacts in Outlook when I try to import a prepared .csv file?

Tags: windows-xp, microsoft-outlook, import

XP SP3, Outlook 2003.

When I follow all the directions, I get to the import and export wizard. I follow it, selecting .csv import.

However, when I get to the choice of folders to import into, my contact folder is not there, only my Archive folders.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SUCCESS!

This url http://acnsweb.colostate.edu/wmabexport/outlook_import.htm gave me a clue. When I added the extra folder, for some reason, suddenly my contacts folder became visible.